# can't run javascript loop in browser bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have this javascript code which does not run in the form of bookmarklet. What the code do is it selects all the elements with the class "btn" and clicks on it using javascript's click() function.
The code is:

```
javascript:(
    function(){
        alert('started');
        var tn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
        for (var i=0;i<tn.length; i++) {
            tn[i].click();
        }
        alert('ended');
    }
)
()
```

And I am testing it on-

```
<button class="btn" onclick="alert('1')">Click</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="alert('2')">Click</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="alert('3')">Click</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="alert('4')">Click</button>
```

The first and last alert (stated and ended) are shown but the html buttons are not even clicked because i see no alerts. Chrome console is showing no errors.

pasting this code at the end of the body works as expected :

```
</script>
    alert('started');
    var tn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
    for (var i=0;i<tn.length; i++) {
        tn[i].click();
    }
    alert('ended');
</script>
```

I believe there is something horribly wrong in my code like syntax or formatting or some silly mistake that I am not able to figure out on my own till now.

NOTE: I have not much experience with javascript and I am messing around with it for 2 months so pls excuse my stupidity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if document.getElementsByClassName('btn') returns any elements. May be you have a problem in your test setup.

Comment: Tested this and i noticed something silly. Somehow I managed to paste wrong test code in my question. The actual code had some function name spelling mistake. My bad

Answer (score 1):

How did you add the bookmarklet? 
With me everything works fine.

Just created a small page with some buttons and your code works fine.

Be sure you're creating the bookmarklet correctly.

- In Chrome, click Bookmarks->Bookmark Manager.
- You should see a new tab with the bookmarks and folders listed.
- Select the "Bookmarks Tab" folder on the left.
- Click the "Organize" link, then "Add Page" in the drop down.
- You should see two input fields. Type the name of the bookmark you would like (i.e., CBT Launcher) in the first field.

Hope it works.

Comment: I created this in brackets, and added it to browser by right click > add page on bookmark bar.

Comment: I figured it out, somehow I managed to paste wrong test code in my question. The actual code had some function name spelling mistake.